# Active and Inactive customers

Tags: powerbi, dax

Active customers means customers who have at least one transaction within the past 6 months.

If I select 1/1/2018 to 1/12/2018 the customer how are having a transaction in that particular date period and also having the transaction in past, within the 6 months (GO BACK FROM THE STARTING PERIOD SELECTED IN SLICER)

Inactive customers mean customers who are having at least one transaction in the past +6 months period.

If I select 1/1/2018 to 1/12/2018 the customer how are having a transaction in that particular date period and also having the transaction in past + 6 months (GO BACK FROM THE STARTING PERIOD SELECTED IN SLICER)

ID   DATE  (DD/MM/YYYY)

1     02/08/2017

3     02/01/2017

1       02/01/2018

2       08/12/2018

3      09/12/2018

If the customer having a transaction in the selected period in the slicer  and also having a transaction in the past within the 6 months period then considers as Active 
if the customer having  a transaction in the selected period in the slicer  and also having a transaction in the past +6months period then considers as Inactive

IN slicer I selected the date from 1/1/2018 to 1/12/2018 then

ID '1 '  consider as an Active Id 3 considers as Inactive

Comment: You should edit your post and ask an acutal question. Also, nobody will be willing to open your link with the sample data. Post a minimal sample or a screenshot, which shows your problem. And last, show what you have tried so far so people know you put some effort into this. This way ppl are more willing to help :-)

Comment: @Strawberryshrub  That is .pbix file In that file I import the data. The dates are in slicer visualization based on the selected dates in the slicer, I need count of Active customers mean having transaction at that particular selected time period and also having transaction in within the 6 months previous +6 months means inactive

Comment: @manideep please listen to Strawberryshrub, In addition I suggest you to show the expected result (test cases)

Comment: @Seymour edited my post with test cases